# Como da finish em activity passadas

Tags: android, android-activity

Bom estou com a seguinte duvida, tem como dar `finish()` em `fragment` que ja passaram ?

O caso é o seguinte:

Tenho algumas telas em sequencia onde utilizo para o camarada escolher o lanche, então ele escolhe o pão, clica em próximo, escolhe o tipo do bife clica em próximo, escolhe se quer salada clica em próximo, todas estas vezes ele pode voltar e escolher novamente o produto, porém na ultima tela quando ele clica em efetivar venda, se ele volta deve ser redirecionado para primeira página, no caso do meu exemplo a pagina de escolher o pão.

Tentei dar um `finish()` na ultima `fragment`, porém ela volta na anterior. No caso não posso limpar toda lista de navegação pois existem outros restaurantes para ter acesso, sendo assim devo voltar na opção (no exemplo) de escolha de pão.

São básicamentes `6 activity` em qual eu posso navegar e voltar na escolha do pão

Minha tentativa foi colocar no evento do `onBackPressed()` assim:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    try{
        super.onBackPressed();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FragmentCardapio_.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }catch(Exception e){
        MessageUtil.showError(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Porém da erro !

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: tentou usar `Intent activitquequeroabrir = new Intent(...);` e depois   `activitquequeroabrir.startActivity();`?

Comment: sim, vou atualizar a pergunta

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho atualizei la

Comment: Num sitio fala em *fragments* noutro em *activities*. Afinal são *activities* ou *fragments*?

Comment: É porque a primeira é `fragment` (fragment_caradapio) e as outras são `activitys`

Comment: O erro é porque você está tentando lançar uma activity usando no intent uma classe que é um fragment(`FragmentCardapio_.class`).

Comment: Como corrige isto ?

Comment: opa, agora vi, então no caso, melhor seria voce fazer todas elas fragments, pois assim voce tem maior flexibilidade e um fragment também é uma activity ou funciona igual com a diferença que voce precisa usar um fragmentmanager para chamar as respectivas rotinas, seja com layout dinamico seja com layout static, no meu ver fica mais fácil de lidar, exceto se voce precisar mesmo de ter uma activity

Comment: se no caso voce for usar fragment, pega o exemplo de navigation draw do android studio, ele ja abre e navega entre varios fragments nativos mesmo

Comment: Meu problema não é navegar, esta me atendendo muito bem, o que preciso é quando ocara clicar em voltar, ele vá para cardápio.